# OpenVPN Chaining

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN "chain", similar to what is described [here.](https://www.secure-computing.net/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN/VpnChains)
I have two separate networks, A and B. Each network has an OpenVPN server using a standard "road warrior" or "client/server" approach. A client can connect to either one for access to the hosts/services on that respective network.

But server A and B are also connected to *each other*. The servers on each network have a "site-to-site" connection between the two.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is the ability to connect to network A as a client, and then make connections with hosts on network B. I'm using tun/routing for all of the VPN connections. The "chain" looks something like this:

```
[Client]  ---> [Server A] ---> [Server A] ---> [Server B] ---> [Server B] ---> [Host B] 

(tun0)           (tun0)          (tun1)          (tun0)          (eth0)          (eth0)
```

The whole idea is that server A should route traffic destined to network B through the "site-to-site" VPN set up on tun1 when a client from tun0 tries to connect.

I did this simply by setting up two connection profiles on server A. One profile is a standard server config running on tun0, defining a virtual client network, IP address pool, pushing routes, etc. The other is a *client* connection to Server B running on tun1. With ip_forwarding enabled, I then simply added a "push route" to the clients advertising a route to network B.

On server A, this seems to work when I look at tcpdump output. If I connect as a client, and then ping a host on network B, I can see the traffic getting passed from tun0 to tun1 on Server A:

> tcpdump -nSi tun1 icmp

The weird thing is that I don't see Server B receiving that traffic through the tunnel. It's as if Server A is sending it through the site-to-site connection like it should, but server B is completely ignoring it. When I look for the traffic on Server B, it simply isn't there.

A ping from Server A --> Host B works fine. But a ping from a client connected to Server A to host B does not.

I'm wondering if Server B is ignoring the traffic because the source IP does not match the client IP pool that it hands out to clients? Does anyone know if I need to do something on Server B in order for it to see the traffic?

This is a complicated problem to explain, so thanks if you stuck with me this far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution to this. There is no need to have multiple/redundant VPN connections in the way that Answer #1 describes. Nor do I think it would have done anything to solve my problem, as much as I appreciated the feedback.

The problem is due to the fact that an OpenVPN server will only accept IP traffic through the tunnel of the connected client, if the source IP address matches what the server assigned the client when the tunnel was established. Traffic originating from any other source IP address going through the tunnel will be completely ignored by the server.

Take a look at the following:

> 10.2.1.15     10.2.0.1/123.123.123.1                                     124.124.124.1/10.1.0.1    10.1.1.20 
>   (eth0)                   (eth0/eth1)                                                        (eth0/eth1)              (eth0)
>   ----------                   -------------                                                         ------------              ----------
>   | Host A |-------------| Gateway 1 |------------------------------------------| Gateway 2 |--------| Host B |
>   ----------                   --------------               {INTERNET}                    ----------------          -----------
>                                 VPN CLIENT                                                     VPN SERVER
>                                 172.16.1.12                                                        172.16.2.1
>                                    (tun0)                                                                (tun0)

So in this example, "Gateway 1" is the VPN client establishing a tunnel to "Gateway 2" as the VPN server. What we want to accomplish is the ability for Host A to communicate with Host B through the VPN. So we set up a standard OpenVPN connection, with Gateway 1 as a client to the Gateway 2 server. Each gateway has a "public" and "private" interface. One for the private network, and one for the public Internet. When the VPN connection is established, each server is using an additional "tun0" interface. Gateway 2, acting as the VPN Server, accecpts the connection from Gateway 1, and assigns it an IP of 172.16.1.12.

The problem, is that Gateway 2 will only accept traffic through that VPN tunnel if the source IP is *172.16.1.12*.

That works fine when *Gateway 1* wants to connect to Host B, but it is a problem when *Host A* tries to connect to Host B. When Host A tries to connect, Gateway 1 acts as a router and routes the traffic correctly through the VPN tunnel over to Gateway 2 (assuming you have your routes set up correctly). If you run tcpdump on the *tun0* device of Gateway 1, you will even see the traffic from Host A going through the tunnel, destined for the other network. But Gateway 2 sees the source IP address as *10.2.1.15* which **does not match** the IP address that it assigned for the connection, and completely ignores it.

So the solution is to configure *Gateway 2* to accept traffic from the 10.2.0.0/16 network through the VPN tunnel. The VPN Server needs to be configured with an *iroute* setting. The procedure for setting this up and all of the configuration parameters are explained on the official OpenVPN website [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope) so I will not re-explain it in this post.

I suggest that when you read this documentation, take special note that you need to use *client-config dirs (CCD)* in your OpenVPN configuration in order to use *iroute*. Make sure you read that part of the documentation carefully. You will also, of course, need to set up routes on all of your gateways, so they know how to route the traffic through the VPN tunnel. Referencing the diagram above, you would still need to add a route on *Gateway 2* like this:

> route add -net 10.2.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 172.16.1.12 tun0

and on Gateway 1 like this:

> route add -net 10.1.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 172.16.2.1 tun0

In order for the traffic from the Host B to properly route through the VPN when trying to connect to Host A.
In my particular case, Gateway 1 is acting both as a *client* to Gateway 2, but also as a *server* to other clients connecting from the Internet that need access to Host A. So I needed to create two interfaces, tun0 and tun1, so that one could be used for the client connection to the other network, and the other could be used as a server for road-warriors connecting in. I also need to add additional routes, so that I can make a VPN connection to Gateway 1 (server) from the internet, and I'm able to route traffic to *Host B* on the other network.
I hope this helps others who are confused about this.

Answer (score 3):

I recently set this up.  The magic I needed was to add correct route commands in the openvpn.confs.

My config is even a bit more complex than yours.  I have three sites, that happen to be EC2 regions: us-east-1 (VA), us-west-1 (CA), and us-west-2 (OR).  Each has its own private IP range as follows:

```
VA 10.1.0.0/16
CA 10.0.0.0/16
OR 10.10.0.0/16
```

The configuration is OR <=> CA <=> VA, with CA forming a central "hub."

### host vavpn

**config va-to-ca.conf**

```
# Sample OpenVPN configuration file using a pre-shared static key
# Port to use: 1194 is the official IANA port number
port 1194

# Use a dynamic tun device.
dev tun

# Remote peer and network
remote 54.241.174.228
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0

# Configure local and remote VPN endpoints
ifconfig 169.254.255.1 169.254.255.2

# The pre-shared static key
secret ovpn.key

# keepalive
keepalive 10 120
```

### host cavpn

**config ca-to-va.conf**

```
# Sample OpenVPN configuration file using a pre-shared static key
# Port to use: 1194 is the official IANA port number
port 1195

# Use a dynamic tun device.
dev tun

# Remote peer and network
remote 54.244.21.223
route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0

# Configure local and remote VPN endpoints
ifconfig 169.254.255.3 169.254.255.4

# The pre-shared static key
secret ovpn.key

# keepalive
keepalive 10 120
```

**config ca-to-or.conf**

```
# Sample OpenVPN configuration file using a pre-shared static key
# Port to use: 1194 is the official IANA port number
port 1194

# Use a dynamic tun device.
dev tun

# Remote peer and network
remote 54.236.173.50
route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0

# Configure local and remote VPN endpoints
ifconfig 169.254.255.2 169.254.255.1

# The pre-shared static key
secret ovpn.key

# keepalive
keepalive 10 120
```

### host orvpn

**config or-to-ca.conf**

```
# Sample OpenVPN configuration file using a pre-shared static key
# Port to use: 1194 is the official IANA port number
port 1195

# Use a dynamic tun device.
dev tun

# Remote peer and network
remote 54.241.174.228
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
route 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0

# Configure local and remote VPN endpoints
ifconfig 169.254.255.4 169.254.255.3

# The pre-shared static key
secret ovpn.key

# keepalive
keepalive 10 120
```

Note well the route commands that go to the other endpoint.  I think if you layout your network and all the IPs at either endpoint, you'll quickly be able to modify my example to your topology.

Comment: I think the only thing I'm doing different from you is that I'm not setting up x2 connections between the servers. I guess I'm not sure why you are doing that? You have CA->VA. Why can't that single tunnel be used for both directions? Why the need for a 2nd VA->CA connection?

Comment: It is a little weird, I admit.  I followed these docs from Amazon: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0639686206802544.  Nevertheless, it works.