# openvpn using client as default route from another client

Tags: openvpn

Im trying this project https://astojanov.github.io/blog/2013/03/31/openvpn-routes.html ,i do step by step but instead of mk-gateway i have a openwrt router,instead of ch-server i have a server on VPS,i test everything on firewall with no success,you can help me for this to work?
Here is my [network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyOvZ.png)
On cell phone i want surf on internet with public ip from openwrt router 190.12.23.45
I apreciate very much your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenVPN Chaining](https://serverfault.com/questions/518454/openvpn-chaining)

Comment: I dont have three servers,only one