# Routing VPN traffic through VPN router

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn

I have looked through lots of Double-VPN / VPN Chain questions over the internet and it looks like my case is a bit special.

Long story short. I have a Raspberry Pi acting as WiFi-to-USB-C dongle (basically it’s the same as WiFi-to-Ethernet one but I just changed the interfaces) with all traffic going through the OpenVPN server I setup by myself ([angristan/openvpn-install](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install)) on VPS. The Pi is set up according to [this guide](https://medium.com/an-internet-website/creating-a-wireless-proxy-vpn-router-with-a-raspberry-pi-3e1b346cfef4) (Except the Tor part) but it’s not that important here. I guess.

All was looking good until I tried setting up an OpenVPN connection as client on my machine connected to the Pi. To be specific, it’s a connection to VPN server from my work, so I cannot configure anything there.

If I got everything right from [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/518454/openvpn-chaining) my *work VPN connection* is getting lost as source IP is not matching up.

To be honest, I have no idea if my setup act like

`PC <-> VPN (VPS) <-> VPN (work) <-> Internet`

or

`PC <-> VPN (work) <-> VPN (VPS) <-> Internet`

or even some third option as my knowledge here is a bit limited (a quite probably)

I would appreciate any help or clues. Thanks a lot!